# Не хотят работать ссылки в Multi-level push menu v2.1.4

Tags: css3, html5

В общем, не знаю, что и думать, но сие чудо, адаптироанное под мой сайт, не хочет переходить по ссылкам. Скачано отсюда http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs

**Ниже код менюшки**, которая выплавает справа на странице и содержит список ссылок. Если правой кнопкой жать и открывать в новом табе - работает. А если просто, как положено, кликать по ссылке - то ноль реакции (( Может, кто-то сталкивался с подобным? (пока что прописана лишь ссылка на about.html - но она не срабатывает)

```
<div id="menu">
  <nav>
    <h2><i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>MAIN MENU</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="about.html" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>ABOUT COMPANY</a></li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" ><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>OUR CLIENTS</a>
        <h2><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>clients</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>PARTNERS</a>
        <h2><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>partners</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li><a href="contactus.html"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>FEEDBACK</a></li>
      <li><a href="address_map.html"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>CONTACTS</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, если убрать в этой строке

```
<li><a href="about.html" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>ABOUT COMPANY</a></li> тэг <li>.
```

то ссылки работают на ура. Иначе - нет.